# Keep NSFW questions out of Hot Questions List

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, sidebar

[This](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28259)

[image]

was on the "Hot Network Questions" list on Stack Overflow for most of today.

It's fine if they want to discuss that on their site, but it is totally inappropriate for Stack Exchange to make this sort of thing appear on the work computers of programmers who are just trying to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: I expect a status declined on this... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238581/213575

Comment: @Braiam: Huh. Actually, that looks like Shog would be fairly favorably disposed toward this. It's not like PubicHair is a valid programming language. (Is it? I really really hope not.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Is a perfectly valid anatomical terminology...

Comment: What, specifically, makes the title NSFW?  I mean, I can at least *respect* that it's a topic that you may not want to see while at work...

Comment: Uhm, the word "pubic" bothers you? Don't click the link if you don't want your network administrator to notice that you're checking out questions about pubic hair. As Braiam has stated "pubic" is a perfectly acceptable anatomical term, as such I cannot see how it is NSFW.

Comment: People, come on. I've never worked at a place where I could freely talk about the pubic hair of anime girls, and neither have *most people*. While I don't necessarily agree that we should take action to try and suppress certain things from appearing in the "hot network questions" pane, I think we can at least agree that this isn't something you want your boss reading over your shoulder. Also "pubic is an anatomical term therefore safe for work" is a complete non sequitur. Lots of things are NSFW without being not profane.

Comment: @meagar:  It isn't that I disagree with you - yes, I don't feel that sort of thing should be one of your open tabs while you're working, nor would I want my boss to glance over my shoulder and suddenly get the wrong idea about me.  At the same time, I would expect anyone in that situation - both boss and employee - to be mature about it.  "It appeared in the side bar.  Stack Overflow has some curious algorithms. Anyway, I'm busy looking up how to *foo* the *bar*..."

Comment: @Makoto I'm in complete agreement. The point I take objection to is the argument that it's actually A-OK to talk about "anime girls pubic hair" at work, because "pubic" is an anatomical term.

Comment: How do you determine a NSFW question to keep out of Hot Questions, then?

Comment: I think HNQ itself is not work-friendly, as its explicit purpose is to distract you into visiting other network sites.

Comment: Too much distress to a programmer's brain, no red squiggles under that misspelled keyword.

Comment: Even the entirety of SO is NSFW, it eats up a good deal of time that could be spent cramming out code, answering phone calls or creating TPS reports. So just have the admins block the site entirely.

Comment: HNQ should be optional/collapsed

Comment: @meagar I've never worked anywhere where I *couldn't* talk freely about the pubic hair of anime girls, and nor have most of my friends; I thought that most people got to be free from disapproval or punishment over such non-issues once they became adults and ceased to be under the rule of schoolteachers. I'm not sure whether this means that Canada is more puritan than the UK or that I just have a strange social circle and work history, but either way the stuffy, speech-regulating workplaces you describe are certainly not as close to universal as you and your upvoters seem to think they are.

Comment: In some countries (like the US), the legal precedent for sexual harassment is very broad.  Merely having suggestive words or images on one's screen, where someone sensitive might see them, has been known to elicit harassment charges.  Regardless of the absurdity, it's a practical concern.

Comment: @Erno - Any ad-blocker can remove HNQ using the XPath `//div[@id='hot-network-questions']`.  Your choice, just as with anything on the Web...

Comment: @TobySpeight - I know but I don't trust adblockers (especially at work) because they have access to the DOM. As entertaining the HNQ can be I prefer a clean site and I consider that a job of the SO team for the layout and our job for the contents

Answer (score 39):

We have a list of words that cause questions to not appear in that list. I'm going to get 'pubic' on that list.

While *perfectly* SFW academic questions from say .. Biology or Health wouldn't be a problem, I think those appearing would be a pretty big edge case.

The contents of that list isn't public, and won't be made public. Let's just say we want to keep likely trigger words out of the hot questions list, and occasionally things that make folks check to see if anyone was looking over their shoulder.

Comment: Aren't you afraid you now opened up a path for users to demand adding all kinds of words that list? It is downhill from here...

Comment: I think it's been mentioned before. Folks can _ask_, and I'd rather that they do even if it means a bit of noise between things that help us make the list very unlikely to disturb anyone. We're pretty particular about what we keep out of the list, but cases like this really do help us make it better.

Comment: It's also very hard to write a post containing the words 'public' and 'pubic' when you have dyslexia. I'm just putting that out there as an achievement.

Comment: I bet that ["aliens", "toilet", "sexual"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25670688#25670688) will never make it into hide-list

Comment: It's like the most fun thing ever when you run across a list of naughty words in your code base.

Comment: @gnat: You'd be wrong about at least one of those words: "sexual" is already blocked. As for the other two words. . .  um, if they don't belong in the title, suggest an edit.

Comment: @JonEricson [been there done that](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/303438/revisions "abducted by aliens"). People know how to push the buttons and even [complain at meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7756/31260) when caught doing this. It's really easy to figure how to manipulate the system (except for Stack Overflow, of course)

Comment: I knew a site where visitors were forbidden to use words like "Saturday" in comment threads.

Comment: @MrLister I am _so_ tempted to use our 'warn but not block' feature of the blacklist on an arbitrary day of the week just to see how long it takes for someone to complain about it. "Tuesday? Tuesday? [NIAAAAGRAAA FALLS!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYP1OBZfFK0)"

Comment: @gnat You have the beginnings of a great Haiku there - keep going with it.

Comment: @TimPost Ah, but "Saturday" contains the substring "turd".

Comment: aliens in list / toilets are entertaining / sexual is hot

Comment: a friend of mine was called to senior management once because he 'surfed on sex pages during work' - specifically the homepage of their branch in Es**sex**, England... not everything is as it looks.